# Does a post ban on meta stack exchange effect stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta, post-ban

If you get question banned on Meta, would you also get banned from stack overflow? or are they completely separate things?

Just wondering because I use the same account for both. Also,
When I ask a question on Meta, I have to wait 90 minutes ask a question on Stack overflow.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to work the other way round.  I got suspended on SO, but it did not propagate to SE :)

Comment: OP is asking about question bans, not suspensions.

Comment: Your edit is addressed in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) under "Asking": _"Users < 125 rep, 40 minutes, network-wide"_ That limit is 90 minutes on Stack Overflow, due to how large the site is and how high the traffic is. As a side note, editing your question to add a second, only vaguely related, question is a bad idea. _Especially_ once your question's been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question bans are only ever in effect on the specific site - they do not interact with other sites.

Of course, one *could* get question (or answer) banned on multiple sites - independently...